# dashed line on img after height auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on an application where I have a notification panel with different cattegories. The categories are divided by images and dashed lines, but how can I set the height of that dashed line to auto so it changes its height automatically when an new notification is added.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/hp9cq3k8/3/) which represents the problem.

Normally I have this as my html:

```
<div class="departure-wrapper">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
              <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span class="departure-img">
                  <img class="image" src="img/icons/car.png">
                </span>
              </div>

              <div class="ui-block-b">
                <h4>Vertrek</h4>
                <div class="departure-notification-append"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Where I append with js the new added notifications to the `departure-notification-append` class

```
if (category === 'vertrek'){
               departureHtml = `
                ${departureHtml}
                <div class='notification-item' style='${style}'>
                    <div class='ui-grid-a notification-grid'>
                        <div class='ui-block-a'>
                            <img class='notification-image' id='${id}' src='${imgPath}'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='ui-block-b'>
                            <span class='notification-text'>${shortmessage}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;

            $('.departure-notification-append').empty().prepend(departureHtml);
        }
```

So my question is how can I set the dashed lines to height auto, when I do now the height of the dashed line is 1px or something. I'll hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: The height of the dotted line is controlled by `.departure-img:after`, You can make an element after every image and use javascript to control it's height base on the notification you are appending.

Answer (score 0):

use `:afrer` on parent div like below

```
.departure-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed white;
}
```

try this http://jsfiddle.net/7uygyvwo/

Comment: But now it will take the whole page but there are different wrappers. And they need to resize when an notification is getting added